# how to update the sqlite database in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am new to ios app development.This is the code for update the  sqlite database i am using but its not updating it shows data base is locked.Any help.

```
-(BOOL) updateSignalCode:(NSString*)deviceString  buttonType:(NSString*)name
{
const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"database Opened");
         sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 800);
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update deviceDetail Set deviceId = '%@' where buttontype = '%@'",deviceString,name];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Query Executed");

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                NSLog(@"Database Updated");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error while updating.%d %s",sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: use fmdb library for sqlite and this problem occurs due to you didn't copy sqlite file to document directory .

Comment: copied and tried not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your sqlite file to document directory in appdelegate .

```
- (void)createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"%@",[self getDBPath]);

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self getDBPath]];
    if (success){
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];// replace name of sqlite here 
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:[self getDBPath] error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


-(NSString *)getDBPath{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"]; // replace name of sqlite here 
    return  dbPath;
}
```

**In Appdelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   [self createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];  
  return YES;
}
```